# spark Scala data frame select

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert a pyspark code to spark Scala and i am facing the below error:

pyspark code

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
valid_data = bcd_df.filter(fn.lower(bdb_df.table_name)==tbl_nme)
.select("valid_data").rdd
.map(lambda x: x[0])
.collect()[0]
```

From `bcd_df` dataframe I am getting a column with `table_name` and matching the value of `table_name` with the argument `tbl_name` that i am passing and then selecting the valid_data column data.

Here is the code in spark scala.

```
val valid_data =bcd_df..filter(col(table_name)===tbl_nme).select(col("valid_data")).rdd.map(x=> x(0)).collect()(0)
```

Error as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`abcd`' given input 
columns:
Not sure why it is taking abcd as column.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Version
[scala2.11.8](/questions/tagged/scala2.11.8)
[spark2.3](/questions/tagged/spark2.3)

Answer (score 0):

Enclose **`table_name`** column with **`quotes(")`** in `col`

```
val valid_data =bcd_df.filter(col("table_name")===tbl_nme).select(col("valid_data")).rdd.map(x=> x(0)).collect()(0)
```

Comment: Thank you Shu i am able to get the valid_data as string. After that i am doing a regex as below val regex = "\\W+"
val newAddress = regex.replaceAllIn("123 Main Street", "x") and the error as value replaceAllIn is not a member of String. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: After that val names= for (x  <- above_names if x.startsWith("Jef") == false && x.startsWith("Jor") == false) and again error as value startsWith is not a member of Any.Any help is appreciated